# gRPC: Rate limiting an API on a per-RPC basis

Tags: go, grpc

I am looking for a way to rate-limit RPCs separately with high granularity, and to my dismay, there are not many options available for this issue. I am trying to replace a REST API with gRPC, and one of the most important features for me was the ability to add middleware for each route. Unfortunately, [go-grpc-middleware](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware) only applies middleware to an entire server.

In my imagination, an ideal rate-limiting middleware for gRPC would use similar tricks as [go-proto-validators](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators), where the proto file would contain configurations for the ratelimiting itself.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing your own [server interceptor](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#ChainUnaryInterceptor)? `go-grpc-middleware` is built on top of interceptors. Implementing your own could allow you to specify rate limiting based on request information.

Comment: interesting idea, however I am unsure if there is a way to distinguish which RPC is called via interceptors. Seems promising though.

Comment: figured out something that should make ratelimiting possible, UnaryServerInfo.FullMethod seems to show a pretty distinct identifier for the RPC

Comment: You should also be able to inspect the `req` argument to find out even more specific info if you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured I could post a snippet for reference of how this would look like in practice, using [go-grpc-middleware](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware) `WithUnaryServerChain` and a unary interceptor.

The idea is to add a `grpc.UnaryInterceptor` to the server, which will be invoked with an instance of `*grpc.UnaryServerInfo`. This object exports the field `FullMethod`, which holds the qualified name of the RPC method being called.

In the interceptor you can then implement arbitrary code before actually calling the RPC handler, including RPC-specific rate limiting logic.

```
// import grpc_middleware "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware"
// import "google.golang.org/grpc"

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
        // WithUnaryServerChain is a grpc.Server config option that accepts multiple unary interceptors.
        grpc_middleware.WithUnaryServerChain(
            // UnaryServerInterceptor provides a hook to intercept the execution of a unary RPC on the server. info
            // contains all the information of this RPC the interceptor can operate on. And handler is the wrapper
            // of the service method implementation. It is the responsibility of the interceptor to invoke handler
            // to complete the RPC.
            grpc.UnaryInterceptor(func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (resp interface{}, err error) {
                // FullMethod is the full RPC method string, i.e., /package.service/method.
                switch info.FullMethod {
                case "/mypackage.someservice/DoThings":
                    // ... rate limiting code
                    // if all is good, then call the handler
                    return handler(ctx, req)
                }
            }),
            // other `grpc.ServerOption` opts
        ),
    )
```

Comment: ♦ can you explain how rate limiting code is written here, I am trying the same with this package https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter, but somehow if i set 10 req per minute, on the first minute it allows only 10, which is as expected, but from every next minute it only allows 1, rest are dropped.